# How to have default imports for all my spec files in TypeScript?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

Here's a really simple spec file for unit testing a TypeScript + React application:

```
import * as React from "react"; // COMMON

import * as chai from "chai"; // COMMON
import * as chaiEnzyme from "chai-enzyme" // COMMON
import * as sinon from "sinon"; // COMMON
import * as sinonChai from "sinon-chai"; // COMMON

import { expect } from "chai"; // COMMON
import { shallow } from "enzyme"; // COMMON

import Hello from "./Hello";

describe("Hello", () => {

    chai.use(chaiEnzyme()); // COMMON
    chai.use(sinonChai); // COMMON

    let hello = shallow(<Hello name="Willson" />);

    it("should render correctly", () => {
        expect(hello).to.have.tagName("div");
    });

    it("should have correct prop values", () => {
        expect(hello).to.have.text("Hello, Willson");
    });

});
```

I see myself using the lines with `// COMMON` being used on every spec file. **Is there a TypeScript way to do this by default on all my files matching this: `/Spec\.(ts|tsx)/`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one thing you can do to mitigate the problem a bit.

First create your `common.ts` like this:

```
//Collect and re-export all of your COMMON imports

import * as React from "react"; 
export {React};

import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
export {ReactDOM};

//More import/exports goes here
```

Then in your spec file you need to have only one import:

```
import * as Common from './common';
```

Later in spec file you use them like:

```
private static childContextTypes = 
{
    extender: Common.React.PropTypes.object,
    form: Common.React.PropTypes.object
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for... But I've moved on to Jest test framework and that one allows me to have some global variables/functions like `expect`, `should`, `it`, etc... And my problem is solved.

Comment: I'm accepting this because it feels like it's the only way if you can't declare some globals.